# Один SQL запрос выдает разный результат

Tags: php, mysql

Выполняю в php

```
$sth = con_pdo()->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `jointbase` WHERE `create_cat` = 1054 group by brand"); 
$sth->execute(array()); 
$number_of_rows = $sth->fetchColumn();
```

Результат: $number_of_rows содержит число 3.

Этот же запрос через SQL в phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `jointbase` WHERE `create_cat` = 1054 group by brand
```

результат 358

Как такое может быть?

Comment: Но order by id ничего не меняет

Answer (score 2):

вы выполняете запрос с группировкой, ответом служит набор строк с подсчитанным `count` для каждой группы (то есть число строк более одной).
Поскольку вы не задаете порядок выборки `order by`, а сам по себе он никак не регламентирован вы можете получать разные результаты не то чтобы в разных средах выполнения, но и даже при выполнении одного и того же запроса подряд.

Поэтому если хотите получать результаты в одинаковом порядке на разных клиентах явно укажите порядок сортировки результатов запроса `order by`